# Format Date Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format

How to format a string that looks like this

> Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012

into yyyy-mm-dd i.e.

> 2012-12-08

From browsing the [web](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/), I found this piece of code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, I am unable to modify it to accept the first line (Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012) as a string and format that into the yyyy-mm-dd format.

What should I do about this? Should I be attempting to modify this? Or try another approach altogether?

Update: I'm using this from your answers **(getting error: Unparseable date: "Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012")**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat srcFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.JAPANESE);
        SimpleDateFormat destFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.JAPANESE);
        Date date = srcFormatter.parse("Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012");
        String destDateString = destFormatter.format(date);
       /* String dateInString = "Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012";*/
        System.out.println(destDateString);

        /*try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: The first String uses words in english so you should give a Locale to SimpleDateFormat. `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`.

Comment: Don't think this works, I've updated the qn to be more specific. See String dateInString = "Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012";

Comment: You actually have 2 problems. 1) you need 2 date formats (as stated by Warlord and SubhrajyotiMajumder). 2) If you don't give a locale and execute the code on a jvm which default language is not English, it will not be able to parse the words.

Comment: I've updated the code to include yours and SubhrajyotiMajumder's answers, but I can't get it to work. the string is still unparseable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateInString = "Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = parse.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Change your formation to this `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Thanks..

Comment: why would you choose English over Japanese as suggested by the answer above?

Comment: it works perfectly for me that's why! if you want locale i japan then you can change it!!

Comment: where are you using the parse variable?

Comment: I update my answer! I forget to update variable name!! now take a look!

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
SimpleDateFormat srcFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.JAPANESE);
SimpleDateFormat destFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.JAPANESE);
Date date = srcFormatter.parse("Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 JST 2012");
String destDateString = destFormatter.format(date);
```

Comment: + provide locale. Or it would only work if the default language is english.

Comment: @Subhrajyoti Majumder: he wans output in this format `2012-12-08`

Comment: @Subhrajyoti Majumder - the string is still unparseable

Answer (score 1):

You need two `SimpleDateFormat` objects. One to parse the date from the string using `parse()` method and the second one to output it in desired format using `format()` method. For more info about date formatting check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).